# Counting Row if it matches x out y Criteria in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have 8 criteria I need to look at, and I want to bring back the count of people who are matching various counts of criteria, so for instance I want the count of people who match all 8 criteria(which is easy with countifs), I want the count of people who match 6 out of the 8 criteria, I want the count of the people who match 4 out of the 8 criteria, etc etc...

I know what I want to do, but it isn't working for me. I want to set it up by department a `Countifs(data!E:E, "IT",Sum(IF(data!A:A >B3, 1, 0), IF(data!B:B > C3, 1,0), IF(data!C:C > D3, 1,0), etc...)),>=5)`

Basically I want to count each employee in the "IT" department IF They meet 5 of the 8 criteria(I am using the sum of the criteria...each criteria met gets 1, otherwise its 0---if the sum of these is >=5 they are meeting 5 or more criteria as each one met is given 1 and added to the other ones that are met).  I get an error with this formula, and I know there is something wrong with it but I feel I'm pretty close to having it right...

How can I count the number of rows where the employee in a specific department meets x of the 8 criteria we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT` with arrays. Dont worry about converting booleans to 0/1 because it is done automatically when adding/multiplying arrays. You formula should look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((data!E:E="IT")*((data!A:A>B3)+(data!B:B>C3)+(data!C:C>D3)+(etc)+(etc)>=5))
```

p.s. I assume that `data!E:E="IT"` is a pre-condition that does not *add* to the sum of matching criteria. If it's not the case, just add it to the sum like the others.

Comment: tried typing it in exactly as you have it using both CTRL+Shift+Enter for the array version and normally but still get the same error I was getting with mine:  "There's a problem with this formula" and the entire formula is highlighted

Comment: Whoops...missed taking the ,1,0 out of the last formula...it works as intended! Thanks!